# How to convey variable numbers in corpus?

Tags: javascript, nlp.js

The documentation examples are simple and clear so kudos for that but I have a simple question.

I would like to know how to structure data that is a bit more complicated than the greeting examples and I do not know how to move forward.

So for example, the app I am trying to create centers around 3 words:

- switch port site

sites contain switches, switches have ports and ports connect to each other across switches.

Switches each have a name(or number) and ports each have a number.

The user says thing like "On site 3 connect switch 5's port 3 to switch 7 port 4"

The result is a data structure such as:

```
{
  site:3
  switches:[{number:5, port:3},{number:7, port:4}],
  action:function(){
        switches[0].connect(switches[1])
   } 

}
```

The data structure could be anything as long as it is consistent.

**Question**

I would like to know how to structure data that is a bit more complicated than the greeting examples and I do not know how to move forward.

The example below is an example of the kind of data I want to work with. I feel like all the numbers should be "variables" instead of hard coded and I don't know how  to convey that in NLP.js. Is there a way to do this? What am I missing?

```
manager.addDocument('en', 'switch 3 port 1', 'switch.create');
manager.addDocument('en', 'switch', 'switch.connect');

manager.addAnswer('en', 'switch.create', '{ switches:[{name:undefined,port:undefined}]}');
manager.addAnswer('en', 'switch.create', `{ switches:[{name:3,port:1}]}`);
manager.addAnswer('en', 'switch.connect', `{ switches:[{name:3,port:1}]}`);
```